# How to reshape the dimension of image in python

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Say I have training images `X_train.shape` = (32,32,3,1000). Which means there is 1000 images and each of them have size 32x32 with 3 color channel. It is in a list of list form. I would like to make it have a shape (1000, 32, 32, 3). I know I could use for loop manually change the it to the shape I want, but I wonder is there any function in `numpy` or `tensorflow` could do it quickly and easily?

Comment: No, I believe they are not talking about what I am asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.moveaxis`.

```
import numpy as np

X_train = np.random.rand(32, 32, 3, 1000)
print(X_train.shape)

X_train_new = np.moveaxis(X_train, 3, 0)
print(X_train_new.shape)
```

Here 3 - source index, 0 - destination index.

Output

```
(32, 32, 3, 1000)
(1000, 32, 32, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a list of list first cast it to a numpy array or a tensor:

Using numpy:

```
X_train = np.array(X_train)
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (1000, 32, 32, 3))
```

Using TensorFlow:

```
X_train = tf.cast(X_train, dtype=tf.float32)
X_train = tf.reshape(X_train, shape=(1000, 32, 32, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `np.einsum`.

```
>>> X_train_new = np.einsum('ijkl->lijk',X_train)
>>> X_train.shape
(32, 32, 3, 1000)
>>> X_train_new.shape
(1000, 32, 32, 3)
```